# Where can I find a list of all Notices of DMCA removal from Google Search?

Tags: seo, dmca

We received some emails from google about DMCA removal from Google search results notice.

> Google has been notified, according to the terms of the Digital
>   Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA), that some of your materials allegedly
>   infringe upon the copyrights of others. The URLs of the allegedly
>   infringing materials may be found at the end of this message.

We deleted some of those messages a long time ago before we start to remove the copyrighted images from our website, so we're not sure that we handled all the emails.

Is there a way to access the list of all notices of DMCA removals? How can we see the remaining unresolved DMCA notices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check DMCA Notices on Lumen Database: https://www.lumendatabase.org/

You can search with a domain name or a subject, then it will display the results. You can sort, or fiter these results as required.